# how to get all input inside a tr with jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a tr with a class set. In this tr, I have some inputs and a button. I would like to fill a variable param with all the name as key and values as values so that I can do a $get.

What I have so far is working with looking up through each input as they each have a different class name but with many inputs, it will be difficult to manage.

So in fact, I have some input hidden and input text with name and values:

```
<tr class="line">
<input id='' class='' type='hidden' name='sensor_id' value='1' />
<input id='' class='' type='hidden' name='when' value='2014-02-24 05:00:03' />
<input id='' class='' type='text' name='val' value='0366167' />
<input id='' class='' type='checkbox' name='train' value='True' checked />
<button id='' class='' type='' name='button' value='update' src=''>update</button>
</tr>
```

And I would like to end up with a var param that will be like {sensor_id: 1, when: ..., val: ...}

Then for the rest, I know how to do the get.

Thanks for your help,

John.

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
var myArray = new Array(); var i = 0:    
$('.line input').each( function() {
   myArray[i++] = { $(this).attr('name') : $(this).val() }
});
```

Comment: observe that just $('.line input') will return an intersting array from where you can get your data. The foreach I just use to get the array you asked for

Comment: And how would you use the closest to get it from the button that was clicked? $(this).closest('.line input').each... ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use $(".line > input") to get all the inputs inside that tr label, the you can use the "each" function over that to get every attr you need in the collection...

something like

```
var myAnswerObj = {};
$(".line > input").each(function(idx, item){
   myAnswerObj[$(item).attr("name")] = $(item).attr("value") 
})
```

the each api [each](http://api.jquery.com/each/)

Hope that help